# Как отменить фокус

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, kendo

Такой вопрос, на странице есть элементы. При табуляции можно осуществлять навигацию по этим элементам, то есть при нажатии на TAB каждый следующий элемент попадает в фокус. Задача заключается в том, чтоб на некоторых элементах фокус не работал и пропускал каретку фокуса на следующий элемент [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может добавить [`tabindex: -1`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Общие_атрибуты/tabindex)

Comment: @diraria как вариант, не подумал как-то об этом))

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/focus-blur#разрешаем-фокус-на-любом-элементе-tabindex

Comment: @diraria напишите ответ, закройте вопрос

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, написал. Мне казалось, что такой вопрос уже задавался, и можно было бы закрыть дубликатом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте [`tabindex: -1`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B/tabindex) к элементам, которые должны пропускаться.

[Вот](https://learn.javascript.ru/focus-blur#%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5-tabindex) ещё одна статья на эту тему.